# jQuery mobile select image for later upload

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I'm building a small mobile web application using [JQuery Mobile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_Mobile). Now I want to select an image on the phone and get information about it so I can upload it later from the app. Is this at all possible?

I might be in an offline situation and should still be able to select a image I want to upload.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If your target phone's browser supports [file upload input type](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-media-capture/) and [FileAPI](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) (e.g. iOS 6.0 Safari)

```
<input type="file"  name="image" accept="image/*" capture>
```

then you can let your user pick an existing file, or even use camera to take a shot, and read some attributes of an image file (file name, size, type, modification date).

```js
$("input[type=file]").change(function(){
    var file = $("input[type=file]")[0].files[0];
    alert(file.name + "\n" +
          file.type + "\n" + 
          file.size + "\n" + 
          file.lastModifiedDate);
});
```

You can also make a preview of a chosen file using `FileReader`.

```html
<div id="preview"></div>
```

```js
displayAsImage3(file, "preview");

function displayAsImage3(file, containerid) {
    if (typeof FileReader !== "undefined") {
        var container = document.getElementById(containerid),
            img = document.createElement("img"),
            reader;
        container.appendChild(img);
        reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (function (theImg) {
            return function (evt) {
                theImg.src = evt.target.result;
            };
        }(img));
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
}
```

**Here is working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmatseykanets/R99NY/)**

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Yes it did, I managed to use the reader and read the image as a string "DataURL". Thank you!

Comment: Thanks! @peterm - This is a great working demo, very helpful. I am basing my mobile uploads on your code.